# Proper word splitting for words with apostrophes in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to configure Lucene / Solr to properly index the words coming in from news articles.  As is currently "out of the box" with Solr 3.4 WordDelimitedFilterFactory indexes:
**she's** 
to be 
**she**

but she'll as in "she will" becomes she, ll, she and shell.  I absolutely don't want this to match "shell".  This was not the intended word.

Currently my text goes thru WhitespaceTokenizerFactory, then StopFilterFactory, then WodDelimiterFilterFactory set to:
    generateWordParts="1"
    generateNumberParts="1"
    catenateWords="1" 
    catenateNumbers="1" 
    catenateAll="0"
    splitOnCaseChange="0" 
    splitOnNumerics="0"
    preserveOriginal="1" 
    types="specialtypes.txt"

I tried saying the apostrophe is to be considered an alpha character in specialtypes.txt by saying:
`' => ALPHA`
but then she's becomes a word, as does pony's and company's and that is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect in this case: Scarlett O'Hara?

Comment: I want bug's to be come bug and Arnold's to become Arnold (english possessive) but I want she'll to become she and not shell

Comment: sorry @notdang I misread.  I'd like Scarlet O'Hara to become Ohara in a perfect world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using protected="protwords.txt" as a part of the solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory filter setup: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory

You can add words that would potentially cause issues with splitting on the apostrophe (like she'll, he'll, we'll, we're). This will index them without any further tokenization or filtering, while continuing to break words up on apostrophe for possessives and other uses.

Comment: This worked! I was confused at first because I had protected="protwords.txt" in the  solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory and this didn't help.  It needed to be specifically called out in the solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory section.

Answer (score 3):

Add the

> solr.ApostropheFilterFactory

According to documentation:

> Strips all characters after an apostrophe (including the apostrophe
>   itself).
>
> Example: "Türkiye'de", "2003'te" ==> "Türkiye", "2003".

Comment: This won't work for what I want because I don't want she'll to become she, I want it to remain as she'll in this case.  But I want Bug's to become Bug preserving how Lucene's english possessive filter in WhitespaceTokenizerFactory works

Comment: Also seems the solr.ApostropheFilterFactory was not introduced until 4.8